Autumn raspberries didn't grow back after pruning
I pruned my autumn raspberries in February but they haven't started growing back (I'm in East Anglia in the UK).
They were planted the year before and they did bear fruit. My plot has clay soil and is very flood prone (it's lower than the road in the allotment and has been compacted by walking over it). During some spells of very heavy rain where the water wouldn't drain, I thought it would be a good idea to add as much organic material I could find, and the only thing I had available at the time was bark/pine needles, which I ended up using in large quantities.  That seemed to absorb most of the water. However, after pruning them to the ground in February, they haven't started growing at all, not even a single leaf. I put the prunings into pots and some of them have started growing, there's a couple of leaves on each.
How can I tell for sure my raspberries are dead? And what could have killed them? Did the excessive bark/pine needles made the soil too acidic? Or the fact that they where sitting in water?

If the roots were waterlogged for too long, they might all have rotted out. You can check for sure by digging one of the plants up and checking their root system. You should have some new (white) roots once it's warm and they've started growing again.
If the roots are soft, brown and easily falls off... then they might all be dead. In which case you can try again with the cuttings if they can root themselves, but figure out your drainage situation or they won't last.

+1 for the last sentence. Problems are not problematic, reasons for problems are. Also: the knife test.

I checked the roots, there weren't any white ones.

We have a raspberry bush that started coming back about a month ago, and being in Colorado, US, I would think we have a later growing season than you.
I couldn't say for sure, but if your bush hasn't started sending any new shoots up, it may be done for :(
Our soil is also fairly dense clay, but it's elevated with a fairly dry climate, so if i had to guess, the standing water is a likely culprit. I also wonder if the organic matter sitting in water could harbor mold, but not sure.
